# Creating array fields in console not possible?

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I wanted to add a simple repeating string field to a table in bigquery but the console would only allow me to add a field of the type "record" which then could contain a single repeating string field, but I think that would result in an ARRAY of a STRUCT with one string field.

I used the ALTER table with ADD COLUMN Shelve ARRAY and that worked.
But why does google not allow to declare a field "repeating" in the edit schema tab in the console?
[image: screenshot from console]

By using ALTER TABLE it was possible to create an an array field:
[image: Array of strings field]

Why is this not possible in the console?

Answer (score 2):

In **"Mode"** choose **"REPEATED"**.

[image]

Comment: Oops, my bad. I kept looking for ARRAY and ignored the simple way. Thx!